# Sql select column based on another column not equaling the parameter but contains the parameter in another column with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the long title.  i have been racking my brains for a few hours now and with a piece of paper trying to work out the easiest method of the following.

I have a Order table that holds orders contents like so:

```
OrderID | ProductSKU | Column 3 etc.
```

AND a table for the SKU's

```
SKU|Column 2
```

The content would be along the lines of:

```
1000  |  SKU
1000  |  SKU1
1001  |  SKU1
1002  |  SKU2
1003  |  SKU
```

What i am trying to do is return the SKU Data from the SKU table if the other contains the SKU requested and ALSO has another line to its order.  So in the above example i wouldn't want 1003 order being returned just SKU1 which is part of 1000 due to it having another item.  It is to be a "what others have purchased"

Thanks in advance

The Code im up to is:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM Catalog.Item 
INNER JOIN Orders.OrderLines ON Catalog.Item.SKU = Orders.OrderLines.ProductSKU 
WHERE Orders.OrderLines.ProductSKU = 'MySKU'
GROUP BY Orders.OrderLines.OrderID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The error im getting now is:
`Column 'Catalog.Item.ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Table 1  - Catalog.Item
Table 2  - Orders.OrderLines

Get all SKU's from the Orders.OrderLines Table WHERE The Order Contains a parameter SKU.

======New info======

Catalog.Item Table has columns SKU, ItemName etc (loads of columns to list)
Orders.OrderLines has columns OrderID, ProductSKU

What i want to return is the SKU data (all columns) from Catalog.Item

I want to search the Orders.OrderLines Table for an SKU and return the other order SKUs that were ordered along with the SKU in question.

OrderLines example data

```
OrderID   |   ProductSKU
1               Bag1
2               Bag2
2               Bag3
3               Bag2
```

Item example data

```
SKU       |   ItemName ...
Bag1           Blue Bag
Bag2           Black Bag
Bag3           Pink Bag
```

The results i am afte are:

```
SKU         |     ItemName
Bag3              Pink Bag
```

Based on a search using SKU Bag2  as it is in an order on its own which i dont want but is in an order with another item with Bag3

Hope this makes more sense now.  Sorry for the difficult information before.

Comment: Can you please provide a more concrete example of the data in both tables and the desired output?

Comment: Ive added more above to try and better describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somthing like this?

```
 Select SkuOrderId, @SkuId
 From tblSku
 Where SkuId = @SkuId
 Group by SkuOrderId
 Having count(*) > 1
```

The error you get for your query is quite self explanatory: You can't use any column in the select clause that is not either inside the group by clause or inside an aggrigate function. This is a basic rule in sql group by, and with a good reason to: what will the database choose to select for SKU in your query?

This is the reason that I've used the @SkuId parameter in my query, and not SkuId from the table directly.

After your further explanation, I think this is the SQL query you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CI1.*, OL.*
FROM Catalog.Item CI1
INNER JOIN Orders.OrderLines OL ON CI11.SKU = OL.ProductSKU 
INNER JOIN Catalog.Item CI2 ON(CI1.<YOUR NUMERIC COLUMN NAME> = CI2.<YOUR NUMERIC COLUMN NAME> AND CI1.SKU <> CI2.SKU)
WHERE OL.ProductSKU = @SKUId
```

There is no need to group by in this solution since we use the Catalog.Item table twice with different SKU values but same Numeric column values. Be sure to replace `<YOUR NUMERIC COLUMN NAME>` to the actual column name.

### Update

After the last explanation you provided I was finally able to create the correct fiddle and play with the sql.
I came up with a query based on my last attempt that will provide the desired output based on your final description.

```
DECLARE @SKU varchar(10) = 'Bag2'

SELECT CI.*
FROM Orders.OrderLines OL1
INNER JOIN Orders.OrderLines OL2 ON(OL1.OrderId = OL2.OrderId AND OL1.ProductSKU <> OL2.ProductSKU)
INNER JOIN Catalog.Item CI ON(CI.SKU = OL2.ProductSKU)
WHERE OL1.ProductSKU = @SKU
```

Running this query on the sample data you provided results in the following:

```
SKU      ItemName
Bag3     Pink Bag
```

[Play with it yourself on sqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91d61/11)

**Note**: You could have got the answer much sooner if you would have write your question better.
Whenever you have a question about SQL, the best thing you can do is provide this 3 simple things:
1. DDL (create tables) + DML (insert data) to create your sample data,
2. A verbal explanation on what you want to achieve and your attempts to get there
3. The desired output.

Comment: Im heading in the right direction with that but now having issue.  The code im up to is: SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Catalog.Item INNER JOIN Orders.OrderLines ON Catalog.Item.SKU = Orders.OrderLines.ProductSKU WHERE Orders.OrderLines.ProductSKU = 'FROZEN001001'
Group By Orders.OrderLines.OrderID Having Count(*) > 1

Comment: Not quite giving me the result im after sorry.  I think i didnt explain it properly before Ive edited it again to show a full description with proper example data.  Im just after the SKU data from Catalog.Item.

Comment: It makes sense now.  It was the joining of the same tables that threw me.  +1 for the introduction of a new tool for me to look at sqlfiddle.  Sorry the post was not correctly formatted from the beginning.  I will remember this when posting here again.